# sorting data using dropdown ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, sorting

i want to sorting data and display the result in the view. I'm using codeigniter framework. What i want is to sorting data using ajax when dropdown values change.

[image]

Can someone give me the example code ?

my ajax

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#selectBerdasar").change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    console.log(key);
    var postdata = {key: key};
    var url = '<?php echo site_url('produk/filter/GetFilterJson');?>';
    $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(result);
            $('.col-item').empty();
            $.each(obj, function(key, line) {

             });
        } else {

        }
    });
});
```

});

my controller

```
public function doFilter($key) {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('filter_model', 'filter');
    if ($key == 'termahal') {
        $data = $this->filter->getDataMahal($key);
    } elseif ($key == 'termurah') {
        $data = $this->filter->getDataMurah($key);
    } else {
        $data = $this->filter->getDataAlfabet($key);
    }
    return $data;
}

public function GetFilterJson() {
    $key = $this->input->post('key');
    $data = $this->doFilter($key);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

my model

```
public function getDataMahal($key) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("produk");
    $this->db->order_by("harga_produk", "desc");
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function getDataMurah($key) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("produk");
    $this->db->order_by("harga_produk", "asc");
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function getDataAlfabet($key) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("produk");
    $this->db->order_by("nama_produk", "asc");
    $data = $this->db->get();
    return $data->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example. hope this helps..

**Ajax**

```
   var phone_number = $(this).find('div.number').text();
        $("#recipentno").val(phone_number);


        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          url:"<?php echo base_url('administrator/get_all_sms/'); ?>",
          data: {number: phone_number},
          success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    $(".smsmessage").html("");
                    console.log(data.total);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.total.length; i++) {

                        if(data.total[i].message_type==1){
                            $('<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg">'+
                                  '<div class="media">'+
                                      '<div class="" style="border-radius: 25px; background: #4CC1ED; padding: 1px; width: 100%;  margin-top: 10px;">'+
                                          '<p style="color: #000000; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px; font-size: 18px;">'+ data.total[i].body+'<i style="font-size: 9px;">'+data.total[i].date_time+'</i></p>'+
                                      '</div>'+
                                  '</div>'+
                              '</div>').appendTo (".smsmessage");
                        } else{

                          $('<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-8">'+
                              '<div class="media">'+
                                  '<div class="" style="border-radius: 25px; background: #65CFBF; padding: 1px; width: 100%; height: 50px; margin-top: 10px;">'+
                                      '<p class="sender-img pull-right" style="color: #000000; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px; font-size: 18px;">'+data.total[i].body+'<i style="font-size: 9px;">'+data.total[i].date_time+'</i></p>'+
                                  '</div>'+
                              '</div>'+
                          '</div>').appendTo (".smsmessage");

                        }                              



                    }
                }
            });
```

**Controller**

```
function get_all_sms(){
    $pon_number = $this->input->post('number');
    $single_sms= $this->admin->get_all_sms_for_number($pon_number);
    echo json_encode(array( 'total'=> $single_sms));
}
```